# Tracking user interaction on a website

Tags: javascript, database, tracking

I am trying to track user interaction on a website that I manage myself. By tracking I mean, I want to track which button or widget the user pressed and when and also how much time a user spent and etc. Before I dive into coding something up on Javascript, I just to get an idea what are best options to do such things and possible pitfalls.

Comment: I think that your question is a bit broad. You could use different technologies to accomplish your goal. To listen the events is jQuery, to store the data you have options like PHP or Python.

Comment: There are third party js tools like omniture , comscore that allow tracking at a more granular level across the site. I am not sure if this is an option for you

Comment: Thanks ! Well I already have a backend database in MySQL and framework running on Python. I am just trying to get a basic workflow for the tracking. So for example, clicking a button should , maybe, fire an ajax call and carry out the normal task at the same time asynchronously. How do I achieve that. Could you show an example ?

Answer (score 10):

It's been some time since this question was posted, but I've been working on a simple JavaScript module to do just this.

Rather than using images, it captures event data from user-specified HTML element(s) along side some basic information about the site visitor's browser configuration. The data is then sent to a specified server endpoint using an XHR triggered on the beforeunload event.

Here's a [link to the GitHub project](https://github.com/greenstick/interactor) and an [example page](http://greenstick.github.io/interactor/)

Regarding the code, here's an example of what the HTML would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Interaction Tracker Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="someElement"></div>
        <div class="someOtherElement"></div>
        <div class="conversion"></div>
        <script src="interactor.min.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            // An example instantiation with custom arguments
            var interactions = new Interactor({
                interactions        : true,
                interactionElement  : "someElement someOtherElement",
                interactionEvents   : ["mousedown"],
                conversions         : true,
                conversionElement   : "conversion",
                conversionEvents    : ["mouseup"],
                endpoint            : '/usage/interactions',
                async               : true
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The architecture allows you to easily track multiple elements through multiple instantiations, allowing you to customize which endpoints different interactions are sent to. This allows for clean separation of any server-side pre-processing prior to saving the data to a database.

```
var elementsToTrack = [
    {
        element  : "cssClass1",
        events   : ["mouseup", "touchend"],
        endpoint : "/interactions/c1"
    }, 
    {
        element  : "cssClass2",
        events   : ["mouseup"],
        endpoint : "/interactions/c2"
    },
    { 
        element  : "cssClass3",
        events   : ["mouseup"],
        endpoint : "/interactions/c3"
    }
];

for (var i = 0; i < elementsToTrack.length; i++) {
    var el = elementsToTrack[i];
    new Interactor({
        interactionElement  : el.element,
        interactionEvents   : el.events,
        endpoint            : el.endpoint
    });
}
```

Finally, it's very lightweight (about 5KB minified) and easily extendable to most needs.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to return any value from server, ajax is a bit overhead - I would use image pings (creating image elements with script as source with any parameter you want to send)

For events, bind them to document and check event target (be aware - blur, focus and change do not bubble)

```
document.body.addListener(event, function() {
    var i = new Image();
    i.src = 'script.php?target=' + event.target;
}, false);
```

For time measurement, you could check time that passes between events on elements.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into something like [mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/). It's very simple to integrate and they provide you with the graphic tools to parse large amounts of data. The basic premise is similar to what you said. Fire asynchronous events on specific user interaction, passing along a set of options. You can also integrate it into your Python code, which makes it easy to track when server side actions take place. Example:

```
$("#my_button").click(function() {
  // This sends us an event every time a user clicks the button
  mixpanel.track("Button clicked"); 
});
```

You can explore the docs for yourself. https://mixpanel.com/docs/integration-libraries/javascript

Mixpanel is just one option, but the premise is the same for all. The thing you need to consider is managing that data after it's been collected. Companies like mixpanel provide a nice GUI to make it less of a headache.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics provides a good Javascript library for this:

https://github.com/googleanalytics/autotrack

Of course, it expects you to use Google Analytics in your app, but it has a free version you can use. Check the [comparison between their free and paid services](http://www.blastam.com/google-analytics-360-standard-comparison).