# extracting html element Id or xpath using computer vision

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, vision

I am working on automating an inhouse automation testing software for my firm, I need to extract the X-path, or id of an HTML element when the tester clicks the webpage element like the login button during the manual testing process, need to extract data like element id or x-path, and what type of action he is performing like click, enter or filling the text box, etc. these data would be useful for integrating with my existing selenium script and perform automation testing, currently exploring feasibilities of computer vision. Kindly suggest some ideas to make it possible.

Comment: You might find what you need here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18774715/tracking-user-interaction-on-a-website

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

-I think you need to extract and read HTML of the page separately then perform any concept/Algorithm of computer vision to detect all elements of the page including text , buttons and drop down list....